# How to turn off internet for desktop using selenium (java)?

Tags: java, selenium, networking, selenium-webdriver

I have a test to verify the url when network settings are turned off.
How to turn off internet in selenium using java?

Answer (score 3):

With windows you can use `cmd` commands to turn off internet:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c ipconfig /release");
```

later, you bring it back with:

```
cmd /c ipconfig /renew
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do anything like that with selenium. Selenium is a browser automation tool. You can only do stuff, what you can in a website.

As far as I know also Java API cannot do that. Just run a bash script as @Adnan Isajbegovic suggest.

For mac:

```
String[] env = {"PATH=/bin:/usr/bin/"};
String script = "sudo ifconfig wlan0 down";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(script, env);
```